# No Data Available in Jtable.js MVC 5

Tags: jquery, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-jtable

I get an error and unable to get any data in my table. I am posting my codes for the model, controller and action as below:

Model:

```
public class User
    {
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Role { get; set; }
        public string ApiKey { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

```
 public JsonResult ListAllUser(int jtStartIndex=0, int jtPageSize = 0, string jtSorting = null)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:12932/");
                var request = new RestRequest("api/Users", Method.GET);
                request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

                var apiKey = Session["ApiKey"];
                var UserId = Session["UserId"];
                request.AddHeader("authenticationkey", apiKey.ToString());
                request.AddHeader("authenticationid", UserId.ToString());
                var queryResult = client.Execute(request);

                RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();

                List<User> x = deserial.Deserialize<List<User>>(queryResult);

                return Json(new { Result = "Ok", Records = x }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                return Json(new { Result = "Error", Message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AdminUserList').jtable({

            title: 'User List',
            paging: true, // Enable Paging
            pageSize: 10,
            sorting: true,
            defaultSorting : 'Name ASC',

            actions: {
                listAction: '/User/ListAllUser',
                deleteAction: '/User/ListAllUser',
                updateAction: '/User/ListAllUser',
                createAction: '/User/ListAllUser'
            },
            fields: {
                ApiKey: {
                    title: 'ApiKey'
                },
                Email: {
                    title: 'Email Address'
                },
                FirstName: {
                    title: 'First Name'
                },
                Id: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                LastName: {
                    title: 'Last Name'
                },
                Password: {
                    list: false
                },
                Role: {
                    title: 'Role'
                },
                URL: {
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    title: 'URL'
                }

            }

        });
        $('#AdminUserList').jtable('load');
    });
</script>
```

I havent posted the jquery links on my view, but done it on my project. I did an inspect element and found out that there are Records being passed as Json, but cant get them on the table. It shows "No DATA AVAILABLE".

Comment: you have to pass `TotalRecordCount = # of rows`, as in `return Json(new { Result = "Ok", Records = x, TotalRecordCount = # of rows}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`